# Bulk-edit Strava activities

Tags: strava

In a recent update, Strava modified the "Upload Activity" dialog so that users can set the correct bike before uploading their activity.

I have many activities incorrectly saved against the default bike and others with no bike set, uploaded before I added any bikes to my profile.

**Is there a tool that would let me set the bike I used for multiple activities per submission?**

Answer (score 2):

Strava doesn't support bulk edits, but there is 3rd-party app that allows that - [<strike>Objem</strike>](https://objem-app.appspot.com/)

There is a tutorial for that app at https://www.darkerside.org/2015/12/objem-bulk-updater-for-strava/

Briefly:

1. Go to <strike>https://objem-app.appspot.com/</strike>
2. Connect with Strava
3. Set filters in the IF panel to select activities that you want to edit. You can filter by date and activity type.
4. Set fields you want to update in the UPDATE panel. In your case, you want to check Gear checkbox and select your bike.
5. Hit Execute button to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not a tool but if you are familiar with ruby, the following script can be handy:

```
gem 'strava-ruby-client'

require 'strava-ruby-client'

client = Strava::Api::Client.new(
  access_token: "access_code"
)

#time interval to update
after = Time.new(2022, 1, 1).to_i
before = Time.new(2023, 1, 1).to_i

gear_id_to_be_replaced = "1"
new_gear_id = "2"

client.athlete_activities(after: after, before: before, per_page: 200) do |activity|
  if activity.gear_id == gear_id_to_be_replaced
    puts "Starting to update #{activity.id}..."
    updated_activity = client.update_activity(
      id: activity.id,
      gear_id: new_gear_id
    )

    puts updated_activity
    puts "Finished to update #{activity.id}!\n\n"
  else
    puts "Skipping update for #{activity.id}!\n\n"
  end
end
```

Current condition will change all gears to be replaced with new gear, but you can tweak that as needed after reading the [client docs](https://github.com/dblock/strava-ruby-client).

Answer (score -1):

You can do the same thing with this one instead.

https://bulk-update-gear.herokuapp.com